# Weird random exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Related to [ASP.NET MVC + LINQ exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309235/asp-net-mvc-linq-exception/12597713)

I get 2 exceptions at a random of 8-12 page reloads - which of the exceptions is also random, it could be number one, it could be number two. The exceptions are the following

```
[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumnHeader(Int32 i) +701
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i) +29
       Read_BoardMessage(ObjectMaterializer`1 ) +348
       System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext() +42
       System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +472
       System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
       Website.BusinessLogic.Services.BoardMessageService.GetBoardMessageModelsFromQuery(IQueryable`1 boardMessagesQuery) in D:\Applications\Website.BusinessLogic\Services\BoardMessageService.cs:167
       Website.BusinessLogic.Services.<>c__DisplayClass6.<GetStudentsBoardMessages>b__5() in D:\Applications\Website.BusinessLogic\Services\BoardMessageService.cs:89
       Library.Web.Utilities.RequestScopeCache.Get(String key, Func`1 defaultGetter) in D:\APPLICATIONS\Library\Web\Utilities\RequestScopeCache.cs:66
       Website.BusinessLogic.Services.BoardMessageService.GetStudentsBoardMessages(Int32 classId) in D:\Applications\Website.BusinessLogic\Services\BoardMessageService.cs:89
       Website.Web.usercontrols.ShowMessages.Initialize() in D:\Applications\Website.Web\usercontrols\ShowMessages.ascx.cs:28
       System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3064
```

----- and -----

```
[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element]
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +4539
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +207
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +500
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +41
   System.Linq.Queryable.Count(IQueryable`1 source) +352
   Website.Web.usercontrols.TopMenu.SetStudentMenu() in D:\Applications\Website.Web\usercontrols\TopMenu.ascx.cs:93
   Website.Web.usercontrols.TopMenu.IsLoggedIn() in D:\Applications\Website.Web\usercontrols\TopMenu.ascx.cs:60
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3064
```

The stack trace points to the following code

```
using (var dataContext = new MyDataContext(Config.ConnectionString))
{
   int numberOfBoardMessages = dataContext.BoardMessages.
                Where(boardMessage => boardMessage.BoardMessageClasses.
      Any(boardMessageClass => boardMessageClass.ClassId == currentClassId) && boardMessage.IsPublished).
                    Count();
}
```

I have tried with a blank database with no 'BoardMessages' and the error still occurs. Does anyone have any ideas to what might be the problem?

Comment: It's hard to see how that the line you've provided could be throwing those exceptions. LINQ-to-SQL typically gives deferred execution - is this the entire database operation, or is there more to it?

Comment: Its the only code there is, the Count just explodes, it is really weird...

Comment: You should run SQL profiler, or if that's not available to you use the [`DataContext.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property.

Comment: Good idea. Run your program from the console application and specify the `DataContext.Log = Console.Out`.

Comment: SQL Profiler just gives the normal sql count code, same code as when it works. DataContext logger doesn't output anything when the error occurs.

Comment: Anything at all or anything unusual?

Comment: Datacontext logs nothing at all when the error occurs, SQL Profiler is normal

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600710/entity-framework-system-indexoutofrangeexception#comment17002055_12600710

Comment: Have you dealt with the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like someone needs to use [`TransactionScope`](https://www.google.ru/search?q=TransactionScope&oq=TransactionScope&sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: There are no transactions, just a simple Count.

Comment: Still, data may be picked up in a progress of some `NO LOCK` dirty insertions which can cause problems like those two.

Comment: I will try to implement it, but I do find it unbelievable since I'm the only user on the website and there is no data in the database.

Comment: @JanJohansen of course you find it unbelievable and yourself downvoting my answer instead of providing the info you commented right now into the question.

Comment: Here's an upvote, proving I didn't downvote you, I'm still fiddling with it and you will get some feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: With the TransactionScope the error is gone, but it introduced this error - http://pastebin.com/wcwfWLbL